# How to turn it into a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

What is the form of the for loop code below, if it is converted into a while loop?

This is the code:

```
    def number(a):
        b = 1
        for c in range(1, a+1):
            b*=c
        return(b)
    
    a = 6
    for d in range(a, 0, -1):
        print(number(d),end=' ')
        for e in range(d, 0, -1):
            print(e, end = ' ')
        print('')
```

This is the output:

```
    720 6 5 4 3 2 1 
    120 5 4 3 2 1 
    24 4 3 2 1 
    6 3 2 1 
    2 2 1 
    1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 6
for d in range(a, 0, -1):
```

Here it is saying that a=6, and the for loop is running from 6 till 0, and stepping by -1 each time. To turn it into a while loop you can just do:

```
a = 6
while a > 0:
    a -= 1
    # and so on
```

Assuming your question is that you wanted to turn the for loop into a while loop, that is how I would do it, but I don't see the point unless there is something very specific you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about this line?
After the for line:

```
a = 6
for d in range(a, 0, -1):
```

I still don't understand changing the for loop for the code below, because this line has a for d in it as a prefix:

```
    def number(a):
    b = 1
    c = 1
    while c <= a:
        c += 1
        b*=c
    return(b)

a = 6
while a > 0:
    a -= 1
    print(number(a))
    #for e in range(d, 0, -1):
    #    print(e, end = ' ')
    #print('')
```

The code that I have hashed, is still my problem, what is the solution in that line of code

The output of the program code has just arrived as below:

```
720
120
24
6
2
1
```